# Delegate Syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

If I create a tableview in interface builder and connect the datasource and delegate to files owner there, do I also need to do this in the implementation of said viewcontroller?

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController **<UITableViewDataSource**, **UITabBarControllerDelegate>**
```

ie manually specify  protocol adherence?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting the delegate and datasource from interface builder there seems to be no reason to specify what protocols that class conforms to.

It works without manually specifying them because the language is pretty dynamic and this process of calling the delegate methods is done at runtime without being sure if the object does or doesn't have the required methods.

Only when setting the delegate/datasource from code there is some static type checking to see if the delegate/datasource conforms to the needed protocols.

Bottom line: write them. You get xcode autocompletion, maybe some warning in some cases, code documentation and some OCD fulfillment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Specifying in the code that the class implements the protocols is what tells the XIB that you can make the connections and tells the compiler that all of the required methods from the protocols must be implemented (and a warning should be raised if they aren't).

Technically you can do without them, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try it? Did it work without?

You're only able to connect them in interfacebuilder when you add the UITableViewDataSource and UITabBarControllerDelegate in your header file.

Just don't forget to implement the required methods ([datasource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) & [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) in you implementation. You'll get a warning when you do forget them btw.